# PHP variables returning to "default" in subsequent AJAX calls

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, scope

I am trying to use a variable set in another if statement, but it keeps returning undefined.  This is the PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['bookingTime'])){
    $bookingTime = $_POST['bookingTime'];
    $bookingDate = $_POST['theDate'];
    $dbDateTime = $bookingDate." ".$bookingTime;
    echo json_encode($dbDateTime);
    exit;
}

if(isset($_POST['bookingPwd'])){
    $pwd = $_POST['txtBookingPwd'];
    //Get the $dbDateTime variable???
    echo $pwd;
}
```

The `$dbDateTime` variable is set as an response to an AJAX request and returns just fine to the jQuery, but I need the variable for a database query.  How do I use that variable in the other if statement? I feel like I am missing something really basic in my understanding of php. I have tried with globals, but no luck.

**Update**

Removing the `exit` makes no difference. `$dbDateTime` variable still doesn't show in the second if statement. This is the PHP code I ran to test:

```
if(isset($_POST['bookingTime'])){
    $bookingTime = $_POST['bookingTime'];
    $bookingDate = $_POST['theDate'];
    $dbDateTime = $bookingDate." ".$bookingTime;
    // echo json_encode($dbDateTime);
    // exit;    
}

if(isset($_POST['bookingPwd'])){
    $pwd = $_POST['txtBookingPwd'];
    //Get the $dbDateTime variable???
    echo $dbDateTime;
    echo $pwd;
    $booking->newBooking($dbDateTime, $pwd);
}
```

The variable is set from an AJAX request with a time value grabbed from an HTML table. A modal then opens up for the user to type in his/her password to book the court at the chosen time. I am thinking maybe PHP isn't storing the value as the variable is set in a different action?

**2nd Update**

Sessions work, but trying to pass the value of `$dbDateTime` through the next AJAX call instead.  This is the jQuery code:

```
var bookingTime;
var dbDatetime;

$('.courtBook').click(function() {
    // Find the row
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    // Find the text
    var bookingTime = $row.find('.courtTime').text()+":00";
    var theDate = $('#theDate').text();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?page=booking', 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'bookingTime': bookingTime, 'theDate': theDate},
        success: function(data){
            var dbDatetime = data;
            alert(dbDatetime);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Much wrong, such sad');
        }
    });
});

$('#btnBookingPwd').click(function(){
    console.log(bookingTime);
    console.log(dbDatetime);
});
```

In the last click function the variables turn up undefined. So, how does this work in jQuery?

Comment: [Exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) stops the execution from reaching the second `if`. What I don't understando is how you get it as undefined... If the first `if` is false, `$dbDateTime` is `undefined`, but if it's true, it won't reach that point... Now, if what you are doing is keep sending requests for this php, you might want to use SESSIONs to keep the value from `$dbDateTime` so next time you can access it...

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Are SESSIONS the only way to store a value in PHP? Should it be unset after use or would it automatically overwrite it?

Comment: Are you making two separate AJAX requests?  That is, is this PHP script being called two separate times?

Comment: @AndrewKozak It is called from an HTML table with a time value grabbed from the selected row. A modal then opens for the user to confirm the selected time and put in password. I need to pass the variable to this modal and the db query to update the table. So yeah, the script can be called numerous times, but all from the same place.

Comment: You have to think of it like this php is being fresh loaded each request.  That way, no variable is set, so you'll need a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to keep track of  previous values :D.

Comment: That's the issue then.  The script "forgets" it has ever run before each time it terminates.  Each new instance is as if it were never run before.

Comment: @FirstOne That makes sense. The SESSION is working, so thanks. Seems like a lot of messing around for so little, but at least it is working and I think it is the only option with the structure of my project. Thank you for the explanation, it helped my understanding and actually helped me fix another issue in another project!

Comment: Can you provide the AJAX code so we can see both sides of the interaction and provide a detailed solution?

Comment: I agree with @AndrewKozak's wish for a detailed solution, but if anyone can help finding another question that can be used as a duplicate for the main problem (variable not beeing saved between requests)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML page and your PHP script do not exchange stateful data.

Each time your AJAX code runs in the HTML page, it makes a new call to the PHP script.  Each time the PHP script is called, variables begin at their default state according to the code.  If you want to use a variable from one AJAX call to the next, you'll have to send it along the next time you call the PHP script.

Try adding the value you get back for dbDateTime as a parameter to subsequent AJAX calls, and I think you'll be on the right track.

**Update**

Your AJAX was nearly there.  Try removing `var` here:

```
    success: function(data){
        var dbDatetime = data;
        alert(dbDatetime);
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that as soon as Xmas is over with :-)

Comment: Just tried adding the ajax response as a variable, but it turns up as undefined when checking it in the console. I'll update my answer with my sad try in JS. Sorry for spamming :-/

Comment: It's not spamming; the purpose of the community is to solve problems and record the answers for future reference.  You are now running into a scope issue in your jQuery.  Remove `var` from before `dbDatetime` inside the success callback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works brilliantly. I think this is the better solution for my application. I wasn't aware that you only use `var` when defining the variable and can't use it when defining the value. Now I know and I will never forget ;-) Once again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer provided, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate to others that a solution has been found.